# Finding common set of elements from a Map whose value is a collection in Java using streams

Tags: java, hashmap, set, java-stream, java-11

Let's say I've a HashMap which contains key as a String and value as a Set of Integers (Map<String, Set>).
And say that the map is populated with following values:

```
Map<String, Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("w1", Set.of(1,3,4,6,7));
map.put("w2", Set.of(2,3,4,5,7));
map.put("w3", Set.of(1,2,3,5,7));
```

How can I find common set of values across all keys using Streams in Java? eg: In this case, the common set of values across all keys is **Set.of(3,7)**

Comment: `map.values().stream().reduce(new HashSet<Integer>(map.values().iterator().next()), (s1, s2) -> {s1.retainAll(s2)
; return s1;});` Or simpler: `Set<Integer> common = new HashSet<>(map.values.iterator().next()); map.values().forEach(s -> common.retainAll(s));`

Comment: @JohannesKuhn or avoid unnecessary work by using `Iterator<Integer> i = map.values().iterator(); Set<Integer> common = new HashSet<>(i.next()); i.forEachRemaining(s -> common.retainAll(s));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that using stream is not always the cleanest way.

My idea would be to get the first set and iterate over the rest to check if all of them contain it:

```
Set<Integer> res = map.values().iterator().next().stream()
            .filter(item -> map.values().stream().allMatch(set -> set.contains(item)))
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

This is a concise solution but it checks the first set twice. You can also add a check to see if the map contains any entries.

Answer (score 1):

My approach is to first group the different values and count them. Then only keep those whose count is equal to the number of entries in the map. That works because each set can only contains the value once.

```
map.values().stream().flatMap(Set::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))
    .entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue() == map.size())
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Set<Integer> commonValues(Map<String, Set<Integer>> map) {
    if (map.isEmpty()) {
       return new HashSet<>();
    }

    Set<Integer> intersection = new HashSet<>(map.values().iterator().next());
    map.values().forEach(v -> intersection.retainAll(v));
    return intersection;
}
```

Comment: You might provide your answer with some explanations so that it'll be more useful for future readers.

Comment: Although it works, I think it is worth mentioning that **mutating objects outside a lambda** isn't considered to be a good practice.

Comment: Also, it'll be cleaner to replace `new HashSet<>()` with `Collections.emptySet()`.

Comment: No it is not "cleaner" to sometimes return a mutable object and other times return an immutable one.

Comment: The result can be wrapped by an unmodifiable set as well if see an issue in it. As a general rule mutation of the source-collection has to be avoided, so I don't see an advantage in returning a mutable empty set.

Answer (score 1):

That could be done by utilizing the `collect()` operation.

The **logic** behind this approach is to get a *random set* from the collection of *values*, wrap it with a *new set* to avoid mutation, and then combine all *sets* using `retainlAll()` method one by one.

Even if values are represented by *immutable sets* (like in the example in the question) that is not an issue because they will be *preserved intact*. The only collection that will be *mutated* is a *new set* provided by the *supplier* function inside the `collect()`.

An *issue* could emerge if the map is *empty*.

In this case, any attempt to obtain the *first set* from the collection of *values* will fail. Hence, this case *must be treated* separately as shown in the method `getFirst()` down below.

That it might look like:

```
public static Set<Integer> getIntersectionStream(Map<String, Set<Integer>> map) {
    return map.values().stream()
            .collect(() -> getFirst(map),
                     Set::retainAll,
                     Set::addAll);
}
```

The same logic could be implemented iteratively:

```
public static Set<Integer> getIntersectionLoop(Map<String, Set<Integer>> map) {
    Set<Integer> intersection = new HashSet<>(getFirst(map));
    for (Set<Integer> next: map.values()) {
        intersection.retainAll(next);
    }
    return intersection;
}
```

Method get `getFirst()` is responsible for retrieving a *random set* from the collection of *values*. In the case of empty map it'll return an empty unmodifiable set, otherwise, it'll yield a first set returned by the stream.

*Note* that in this case, it's safe to invoke `get()` on an optional because we expect the result to be present.

```
public static Set<Integer> getFirst(Map<String, Set<Integer>> map) {
        return map.isEmpty() ? Collections.emptySet() :
                               new HashSet<>(map.values().stream().findFirst().get());
    }
```

**main**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Set<Integer>> map =
            Map.of("w1", Set.of(1,3,4,6,7),
                   "w2", Set.of(2,3,4,5,7),
                   "w3", Set.of(1,2,3,5,7));
    
    System.out.println(getIntersectionStream(map));
    System.out.println(getIntersectionLoop(map));
}
```

**output**

```
[3, 7]
[3, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

A generic and potentially efficient solution could be:

```java
public static <T> Set<T> retain(Map<?, Set<T>> map) {
    Iterator<Set<T>> it = map.values().iterator();
    if (!it.hasNext()) {
        return new HashSet<>();
    }
    Set<T> result = new HashSet<>(it.next());
    while (it.hasNext() && !result.isEmpty()) {
        result.retainAll(it.next());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Note the `!result.isEmpty()` which is an early-exit condition. I.e. if the result is empty, then the sets have no elements in common.

Note: this was inspired by the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71335635/5515060) of [MikeFHay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/839128/mikefhay).

---

If you really want to use streams, and can guarantee that the `Set`s are mutable, then you may also use the `reduce()` terminal operation:

```java
public static <T> Set<T> retain(Map<?, Set<T>> map) {
    return map.values().stream()
        .reduce((a, b) -> {
            a.retainAll(b);
            return a;
        })
        .orElse(Set.of());
}
```

But be aware that this modifies and returns the first set in the map.

Comment: The steam-based solution will not handle the map comprised of immutable sets because as you said the first of them will be modified. As a possible remedy, you might add `map(HashSet::new)` before `reduce()`, that'll cause some performance overheads but preserve the source map intact.

Answer (score 0):

This simple version uses stream with set operations to populate `intersections` by finding one of the members and `retainAll` to match all the others:

```
Set<Integer> intersection = new HashSet<>();
map.values().stream().limit(1).forEach(intersection::addAll);
map.values().stream().forEach(intersection::retainAll);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would first recommend to not use streams and just do it simply as shown below. This does remove one element of the map.  You could just do `map.get("w1")` and do one redundant `retainAll`.

Notice since you used `Map.of` which creates an immutable set I had to make a copy to allow `result` to be modified.

```
Set<Integer> result = new HashSet<>(map.remove("w1"));
for (Set<Integer> set : map.values()) {
            result.retainAll(set);
}
```

Here is a stream solution.

To avoid having to use an initializer for a reduce operation I would use the `reducing Collector`. This collector returns an `Optional` so `orElse` had to be used to retrieve the set and allow for an empty map.

```
Set<Integer> result = map.values().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.reducing((a, b) -> {
            a.retainAll(b);
            return a;
        }))..orElse(new HashSet<>());

System.out.println(result);
```

Both of the above would print

```
[3, 7]
```

The solutions shown presume a properly populated `Map`.  A full solution would include checks for

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this is the best solution:

```java
map.values().stream().reduce((s1, s2) -> {
    Set<Integer> s3 = new HashSet<>(s2);
    s3.retainAll(s1);
    return s3;
}).orElse(new HashSet<>());
```

It is a stream on map values reduced by intersecting the sets.